# UTF-8 encoded email not displayed correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email

I have created a registration form with Codeigniter which requires user to click on a link sent via confirmation email. I have encoded this email as UTF-8 and sending it as HTML using:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

User has registered and he has received an email that comprised of only first two letters. 
First word included letter `Š`. Mail broke when it got to `Š`, and nothing was displayed afterwards. 
User is registered via `citromail.hu`.
Is it my mistake or is it mail service fault?

Comment: Have you tried `$this->email->message(utf8_encode($message));`? If that doesn't work, please try [iconv](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
Open the application/system/libraries/Email.php and change the "quoted-printable" string to $this->_encoding.

It will works.